# React Router Dom doesn't recognize url with query params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am facing an issue with using query params and react router dom.

When I do an API call and it returns me a status 200, I redirect the user to the results page with a history.push. So far everything is working fine. However, when I am on the results page and refresh the page, I want to use the url with query params to perform a new search, unfortunately React Router Dom is not able to recognize the url and redirects me.

App.tsx

```
<PrivateRoute path="/search?value=:searchValue&type=:searchType">
  <Dashboard />
</PrivateRoute>
<Route path="/redirection" component={RedirectionPage} />
<Redirect to="/login" />
```

Search.tsx

```
history.push({
  pathname: `/search?${formattedSearch
    .map((search) => `value=${search.value}&type=${search.type}`)
    .toString()
    .replace(",", "|")}`,
  state: search
});
```

This history.push works great and redirects the user to the desired page.

But when I refresh the page with the same url, React Router Dom doesn't recognize the route and doesn't redirect me to the component.

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you and wish you a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Route match params are not the same thing as URL query string parameters.

You'll want to access the query string from the [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object.

> ```
> {
>   key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
>   pathname: '/somewhere',
>   search: '?some=search-string', <-- query string
>   hash: '#howdy',
>   state: {
>     [userDefined]: true
>   }
> }
> ```

[React-router-dom query parameters demo](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

They create a custom `useQuery` hook:

```
const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
```

For your use case, on the page rendering the `Dashboard` you want to then extract the query string parameters. Given `path='/search?value=:searchValue&type=:searchType'`:

```
const query = useQuery();

const email = query.get('value');
const token = query.get('type');
```

### Class-based component?

If `Dashboard` is a class-based component then you will need to access `props.location` and process the query string yourself in a lifecycle method. This is because React hooks are only validly used by functional components.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { location } = this.props;
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  
  const email = query.get('value');
  const token = query.get('type');
  ...
}
```

##### Note regarding path

```
path='/search?value=:searchValue&type=:searchType'
```

The path params are only relevant in the path portion of a URL, you can't define params for the queryString portion of the URL. The above path is equivalent to `path='/search'` from `react-router-dom`'s perspective.

```
<PrivateRoute path="/search">
  <Dashboard />
</PrivateRoute>
```